# I'm new to drawing boxes in the console window, but it's not working as intended. How can I get a regular rectangle?

Tags: c#, console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j98hl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIZyc.png)

square
Move one space up, down, left, or right.
In the case below, I tried to add 3 spaces, but it failed.

I've been thinking for over 3 hours but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: The C language is ***very*** different from the C# language. Don't add tags that might sound similar to what you want, read their actual descriptions. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Besides that, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The console might insert a line feed automatically, if the line reaches the maximum line length. Try to use `Write` instead of `WriteLine`.